# How to use a for loop to iterate through an array

Tags: python, arrays, api

So basically I am getting a list of ids and storing them in an array ids. I want to use these ids to do api calls. Here is my code:

```
url = "https://swag.com"
headers = {'x-api-token': "cool"}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
data = json.loads(response.text)

ids = [element['id'] for element in data['result']['elements']]
for i in ids:
    url_2 = "https://swag.com/"
    survey_url = url_2 + str(ids)

response_2 = requests.get(survey_url, headers=headers)
data_2 = json.loads(response_2.text)
print(response_2.text)
```

so basically I don't know how to separate the ids to run individual calls. How would I go about doing this. With my code it just tries to run all ids as 1 api call.

Comment: This code doesn't look syntactically correct. Please check your indents

Comment: this code runs i just chopped it up a bit to make it simple for this

Comment: The forloop is not indented. But assuming the code below goes inside the forloop, the problem is `survey_url = url_2 + str(ids)` which has to be `survey_url = url_2 + str(i)` ?

Comment: Fix indentation. Read about for-loop. Your question is answered in every book about Python basics.

Comment: the indentation is fine in my actual code this was just a copy/paste error i am sorry

Comment: @jdoe I think I've answered your question. Also, i think `response_2` should go inside the forloop, and so should `data_2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your for loop is constructing a survey url based on `ids` instead of `id`.

Change it to

```
for i in ids:
    url2 = "https://swag.com/"
    # your mistake was using str(ids) here.
    survey_url = url_2 + str(i)
    # proceed further with making the request for this survey url
    # Also, I feel the response_2, data_2 and print(response_2.text)
    # should be inside this for loop
```

An easy way to catch this error would be to put a print statement and print your survey_url.